# Python - loop to assign variable/commands to certain list columns

Tags: python, loops, foreach

I have a question related to loops & lists. I have an ascii file that I import as a csv.

Import code:

```
with open(output_file2) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter="\t")
    d = list(reader)


# The ascii file looks like this:
ID1 30.1 -22.2 6.32
ID2 29.2 -32.1 4.84
ID3 29.6 -30.8 2.12
```

Each line of the ascii file represents an ID value, lat, lon, and voltage. I'm trying to think of how I could use some kind of loop (nested loop?) in order to do some operations on certain columns. For instance:

```
ID1 = d[0][0]
ID1 = colored(ID1, 'blue', attrs=['bold'])

lat1 = d[0][1]
lon1 = d[0][2]

volt1 = d[0][3]
volt1 = float(volt1)



ID2 = d[1][0]
ID2 = colored(ID2, 'blue', attrs=['bold'])

lat2 = d[1][1]
lon2 = d[1][2]

volt2 = d[1][3]
volt2 = float(volt2)

etc etc…
```

Is there a way of doing this kind of thing using a loop (since my input file can have anywhere between 2 to over 200 rows)?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, of course there is a way of doing it with nested loops, possibly with a single `for` loop and possibly a vectorized way with `pandas`. What have you tried?

Comment: Hi roganjosh, I've tried making an nested for loop, but am kind of stuck. Just having a hard time wrapping my mind around how this would be done with such type of loop. Code: 
    for j in range(0,12):
        for k in range(0,6):
            print "Element: ", j, k

Comment: PS: sorry... not sure how to format the code in this comment section

Comment: You cannot properly format code in a comment, but you can enclose in backticks for code highlighting. That said, I recommend you edit your attempt into the question and show the issue. I'm on a terrible phone atm but look up "stack overflow minimal example" on google and give an MCVE